# Difference between exlude and excludeShallow in r.js

Tags: node.js, r.js

What is the difference between exlude and excludeShallow in r.js Why are they used.

Answer (score 1):

[The r.js example build file](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js) explains the difference between exclude and excludeShallow through examples, where excludeShallow would generally be helpful during development.

```
//This module entry combines all the dependencies of foo/bar/bip into one file,
//but excludes foo/bar/bop and its dependencies from the built file. If you want
//to exclude a module that is also another module being optimized, it is more
//efficient if you define that module optimization entry before using it
//in an exclude array.
{
    name: "foo/bar/bip",
    exclude: [
        "foo/bar/bop"
    ]
},

//This module entry shows how to specify a specific module be excluded
//from the built module file. excludeShallow means just exclude that
//specific module, but if that module has nested dependencies that are
//part of the built file, keep them in there. This is useful during
//development when you want to have a fast bundled set of modules, but
//just develop/debug one or two modules at a time.
{
    name: "foo/bar/bin",
    excludeShallow: [
        "foo/bar/bot"
    ]
},
```

[The r.js documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#shallow) further explains that excludeShallow may be useful for rapid development: when using the optimizer through the command line, the excludeShallow option can be used to exclude optimization of a module.